# Office Word Add-in compatibility

Tags: office-addins, word-addins

I have a MS Word Add in and it is rejected by MS when I submit to Office store because it is not compatible with MS Word 2013 and MS Word 2016. But I just want to use my add in in MS Word online environment, how can I config my add on manifest file to prevent using from MS Word?

If it is impossible, can we prevent using from MS 2013? I see this [add-in](https://store.office.com/gyro/clientstore?clid=1033&p1=16.0.8330.5950&p2=6&p3=0&p4=0&ver=16&app=WAW&client=WAC_Word&cv=17.0.8330.5950&ClientSessionId=dd939ab0-d512-e08c-4e41-ead54072e870#/details/WA104380518) only available for MS Word 2016 and Word online only. How can we config it?

Please help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is easy.
You must change your manifest xml. If you add the requirements for Word API 1.1 Office 2013 disappears automaticly when you submit it to the Office Store.

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

For some crazy reason the order of the elements in the manifext xml is important. Add Requirements between Hosts and DefaultSettings.

Comment: It work, thank you very much, you save my life.

I also had trouble when finding a right place to put the requirements tag. In my manifest file it worked when i put it under the Hosts tag